# Get-WindowsUpdate is not working properly

Tags: powershell-5.0, windows-update

Need to patch the remote servers parallely using powershell script. But Get-WindowsUpdate command does not download/Install the patch and also not throwing any error.

```
MySession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cred
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
Invoke-Command -Session $MySession -ScriptBlock {
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
ipmo PSWindowsUpdate; 
try{
Get-WindowsUpdate -IgnoreUserInput -ForceDownload -Install -AcceptAll -AutoReboot -Confirm:$false
}
catch{
Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `$` on MySession

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from comments

1. Your variable is missing the dollar sign.
2. It's considered a bad practice to use aliases in scripts.
3. The sleep commands seem unnecessary, especially the first. The next line will not run untilthe previous completes.
4. Indentation and spacing help to see syntax/flow issues more easily.
5. Splatting also helps with readability/debugging.
6. Verbose can provide valuable feedback for debugging.

   ```
    $MySession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cred

    Invoke-Command -Session $MySession -ScriptBlock {
        $param = @{
            IgnoreUserInput = $true
            ForceDownload   = $true
            Install         = $true
            AcceptAll       = $true
            AutoReboot      = $true
            Confirm         = $false
            Verbose         = $true
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

        Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
        try
        {
            Get-WindowsUpdate @param
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
   ```

Also if you aren't sure they all have the module installed you could add something like this to the beginning of the scriptblock

```
if(-not (Get-Module PSWindowsUpdate))
{
    Write-Host Installing PSWindowsUpdate module.. -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
}
```